# Array of array in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, nsarray

i have a NSArray of twitter_timeline using this tutorial http://tutorials.veasoftware.com/2013/09/20/twitter-api-version-1-1-user-timeline-in-ios-7/
I get my timeline using this code on cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
NSdictionary *tweet=_twitter_feed[indexPath.Row];
cell.labeltext.text=tweet[@"text"];
```

Everything works fine, BUT i want to create another array (NSMutableArray) and insert my _twitter_feed(NSArray) into it and get the same access to twitter_feed.
Something like that:

```
NSMutableArray *mainarray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[mainarray addObject:_twitter_feed];
```

but i don't know how to get text from twitter_array from main array

```
NSDictionary *tweet=[[mainarray objectAtIndex:0]indexPath.row];//??????
cell.labeltext.text=tweet[@"text"];
```

This is doesn't work.

Comment: If you indent your code with four spaces you don't have to use `<code>` tags.

Comment: where you creates `mainarray` and `[mainarray addObject:_twitter_feed];`?

Comment: NSArray *tweetArr=[[mainarray objectAtIndex:0];
NSDictionary *tweet=[[tweetArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `_twitter_feed` is a *NSArray*, you can simply use `[[mainarray objectAtIndex:0]  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` to get it.

Comment: You can also use the syntax literals: mainarray[0][indexPath.row]

Answer (score 0):

Try using `NSMutableDictionary`: (untested)

```
NSMutableDictionary *mainDict= [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[mainDict setObject: _twitter_feed forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", indexPath.row]];
```

and retrieve like:

```
NSdictionary *tweet= [mainDict objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", indexPath.row]];
cell.labeltext.text=tweet[@"text"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the line that is giving you the error:

```
NSDictionary *tweet = [[mainarray objectAtIndex:0]indexPath.row];
```

Now you've added the reference stored in `_twitter_feed` into the your `mainarray`, so this line is effectively:

```
NSDictionary *tweet = [_twitter_feed indexPath.row];
```

Compare this to your working line:

```
NSDictionary *tweet = _twitter_feed[indexPath.row];
```

Those two are not the same. Maybe you meant to type:

```
NSDictionary *tweet = [mainarray objectAtIndex:0][indexPath.row];
```

You can shorten that to:

```
NSDictionary *tweet = mainarray[0][indexPath.row];
```

HTH